# default jetty 7 install, can't access servlets via url

Tags: gwt, jetty

I wrote a small GWT app that includes a websocket servlet. I installed jetty-hightide 7.1.6 on my ubuntu 10.04 server and I cannot access the websocket servlet. However I can access it no problem when running on my local machine for testing. I didn't do any configuration to jetty I simply dropped the war file for the GWT app into the webapps folder and jetty deployed it.

I can access the app itself by going to the expected URL, but I just can't access the servlet via a URL.

the url I use locally is:
ws://127.0.0.1:8888/canvasbattleserver/battleCom
and on the production server:
ws://thelettercliff.com:8080/canvasbattleserver/battleCom

here is the configuration of the servlet in web.xml

```
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>battleServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.thelettercliff.project.server.BattleServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>battleServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/canvasbattleserver/battleCom</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

See if this works:

Edit this file: `/etc/default/jetty`

Look for a line that says

`JETTY_HOST` and change its value to `0.0.0.0`

so it should read as:

`JETTY_HOST=0.0.0.0`

That will make jetty listen to connections on all interfaces.